# Angular Material Datepicker: Can we show multiple calendars?

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material

I am searching for show multiple calendars in date-picker pop-up . Unfortunately I didn't found in this library
Is this feature exist in Angular Material?
https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview

Whenever we click Date input , now we show only 1 calendar month. Instead of that I need to show Current Month, Previous Month and Next Month. As like ng-bootstrap Date picker. Attached link here
https://stackblitz.com/run?file=app/datepicker-multiple.ts

Comment: The example link is broken. It can help us understand the needs.

Comment: @mahender   you can try this out. I was recently working on it and created a lib for it - https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-material-date-range-picker